# Efficent MongoDB queries to get reports from one collection and insert into another

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to consult about how to solve a specific task using MongoDB. I will try my best to explain the whole picture so there won't by an XY problem. It's going to be a bit long so I appreciate all of who get to the end of the topic. I have a collection (lets call it `Cars`) that contains reports. All of the reports contain three main fields:

- name.
- color.
- timestamp.

Those reports contain other fields as well, but they are irreverent for my question. There is only one more field I would like to explain - `new_start`. If `new_start` is located in the report (meaning `new_start: 1`) then I ignore all of the reports that have the same name and color but they are older reports then the report that contains `new_start` (meaning the timestamp is less than the wanted reports). I'll try to explain with an example. Please consider the following reports:

```
report1 - name: ABC, color: black, timestamp: 1581946973
report2 - name: ABC, color: black, timestamp: 1581946963
report3 - name: ABC, color: black, timestamp: 1581946953, new_start: 1
report4 - name: ABC, color: black, timestamp: 1581946943
report5 - name: ABC, color: black, timestamp: 1581946933, new_start: 1
report6 - name: ABC, color: black, timestamp: 1581946923
```

Those reports are sorted by timestamp (from newest to oldest) and all have the same name and color. So the reports that interest me are:

```
report1 - name: ABC, color: black, timestamp: 1581946973
report2 - name: ABC, color: black, timestamp: 1581946963
report3 - name: ABC, color: black, timestamp: 1581946953, new_start: 1
```

Note that if there were no reports with `new_start` then I would handle all of them.

I tried to write a query/code that does the following logic for me: For all of the reports that contain the **same name and color** get all of the reports. If one of the reports contains `new_start` then it should return the reports from the newest until that report.

What I tried (using python and pymongo):

1. Get all of the reports:

   ```
   records = db.query(collection_name="cars", query={})
   ```
2. Iterate thought all of the reports and for each one, perform changes.

   ```
   for record in records:
       other_line_records = db.query(collection_name="cars", query={'name': record['name'], 'color': record['color'], '_id': {'$ne': record['_id']}})
       # changes
   ```

But the problem is that I just get all of the reports and then the code iterates though them and that could take a while because there are a lot of reports and by doing this way I will iterate over the same report.

Here enters the purpose of this whole operation - I would like to merge those reports into one main report and insert it into another collection `merged_cars`. The merge logic I'll do myself after I get the needed reports, but I'll be glad to get help with the other questions:

1. In my suggested way, it will merge those reports in infinite loop. This means that `merged_cars` will have the same reports over and over. I need somehow to keep track of the merged reports. I though of creating the a field `merged_ids` that contains an array of all of the merged ids. That way I would know if there is a new report I should add to the merge. But how should I efficiently check if the report is already merged? Also, is it a valid solution to this problem? Feels a bit odd to save those ids.
2. Currently, I just iterate over all of the reports without actually using the power of MongoDB aggregation. I'm sure that there is a smarter and more efficient way so I won't have to iterate over all of the merged reports over and over again. But I can't seem to understand how to do it.
3. How should I take `new_start` into account?

To summarize, due to my lack of experience in MongoDB aggregation, I can't seem to figure out an efficient way of solving this problem. I will be glad to see some suggestions (please provide examples so it will be easier to understand) on how to approach this problem. As you can see my main problem is to figure out how should those queries look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the MongoDb aggregation we could achieve that.

### Explanation

1. We `$group` all records with the same `name` and `color` and store root documents into temporal field named `data`
2. From `data`, we find all documents with `new_start` + with `$reduce` we return the greates `timestamp`.
3. With `$filter` we match all records with `max_result` <= `item`<sub>i</sub> `timestamp`
4. With `$unwind` we flatten filtered `data`
5. `$replaceRoot` helps use change root structure with `data` <sub>i</sub> sub-document

---

```
db.Cars.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        name: "$name",
        color: "$color"
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      max_timestamp: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$data",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.new_start",
                      1
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $gt: [
                      "$$this.timestamp",
                      "$$value"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "$$this.timestamp",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$data",
          cond: {
            $lte: [
              "$max_timestamp",
              "$$this.timestamp"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$data"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sOAcEA7XCiD)

If you add `$merge` operator as the last step, the reports will be inserted into `merged_cars` collection

```
{
  $merge: {
    into: "merged_cars",
    on: "_id",
    whenMatched: "replace",
    whenNotMatched: "insert"
  }
}
```

### Pymongo

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017').test

pipeline = [
 {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
       'name': "$name",
        'color': "$color"
      },
      'data': {
        '$push': "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$addFields': {
      'max_timestamp': {
        '$reduce': {
          'input': "$data",
          'initialValue': 0,
          'in': {
            '$cond': [
              {
                '$and': [
                  {
                    '$eq': [
                      "$$this.new_start",
                      1
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    '$gt': [
                      "$$this.timestamp",
                      "$$value"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "$$this.timestamp",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$addFields': {
      'data': {
        '$filter': {
          'input': "$data",
          'cond': {
            '$lte': [
              "$max_timestamp",
              "$$this.timestamp"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    '$unwind': "$data"
  },
  {
    '$replaceRoot': {
      'newRoot': "$data"
    }
  }
]


print(list(db.cars.aggregate(pipeline)))
```

> [{'_id': ObjectId('5e658bb6fd9da8cfcc2f5a08'), 'name': 'ABC', 'color': 'black', 'timestamp': 1581946973}, {'_id': ObjectId('5e658bb6fd9da8cfcc2f5a09'), 'name': 'ABC', 'color': 'black', 'timestamp': 1581946963}, {'_id': ObjectId('5e658bb6fd9da8cfcc2f5a0a'), 'name': 'ABC', 'color': 'black', 'timestamp': 1581946953, 'new_start': 1}]

Comment: You are awesome!  A few question if you may. If I change `NumberLong(1581946933)` to `1581946933` I get `1.581946972e+09`. Do you know why? Also, about the merge part - How do I know if I handle reports that were not already merged, without using `$merge`? And future more, It works for me in the playground but in the pymongo `result_docs = list(db[collection_name].aggregate(mongo_pipeline))` returns false (I just copied the aggregation. Any ideas why? Thanks again!

Comment: @vesii I've updated my answer. `NumberLong` in PlayMongo works to avoid `1.581946972e+09`. You can add extra field (date) to trace your changes. You need to put inside quotes operators, commands, etc...

Comment: I see. Is it possible to achieve without `addFields`? I have to use mongo 3.2 unfortunately. Sorry for not mentioning it before

Comment: @vesii Neither we can use `$reduce`, `$replaceRoot`... you need to update MongoDB at least 3.4

Comment: Unfortunately I currently use an old environment that can use MongoDB 3.4 or above. Is it not possible with the 3.2 tools? It will take sometime to upgrade the system. Could you suggest another way maybe?

Comment: @vesii You need to do it with python code manually, with aggregation unfortunately it's not possible

Comment: I see, thanks. So can you maybe suggest a strategy to achieve it? What would be the most efficient way to do it?